# IOS center bottom position view

Tags: objective-c, ios, view, position

I do the following to a loading animation, to place it at the bottom center of the screen.

```
CGPoint bottomCenter = CGPointMake((self.imageView.bounds.size.width / 2), (self.imageView.bounds.size.height * 0.8));  
    self.activityView.center = bottomCenter;
```

(imageView is the full screen splash image)

If the orientation is portrait, it is positioned perfectly, however turning on its side, in landscape or upside down portrait and the animation ends up miles away :S

Does anyone know the correct way to position this loading animation, its for the splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

use `UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation)` and `UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation)` instead of `deviceOrientation==X`

Answer (score 0):

First, look at tkanzakic's answer.
Second, don't use screen bounds, orientate the view by its parent view. If you put your view to the bottom of your parent view and you set the autoresizing mask correctly, everything will be done automatically - no need to check device orientation.

Comment: This does not seem to help, as its on the splash screen, many of the views are not fully loaded, and so do not have the correct width and height, I have amended the code to be like this:

CGPoint bottomCenter = CGPointMake((self.imageView.bounds.size.width / 2), (self.imageView.bounds.size.height * 0.8));  
    self.activityView.center = bottomCenter;

where the splash screen image bounds, represents the correct with and height in any orientation but still fails to sit in the correct postion in anything other than the standard portrait mode

Comment: @Ben_hawk Displaying something what is not fully loaded won't work. This is the correct answer. If that doesn't work for you, it's your architecture to blame. Splash screen is not some special kind of view. Also, you don't need the views to have the correct bounds. You just have to set the autoresizing correctly and when the views get the correct bounds, everything will get resized (and repositioned) correctly.

Comment: it cant be my architecture as its from the phonegap framework, the loading animation is the default one you get with a phonegap project. The reason im trying to move it is, it covers my splash screen image, and so instead I would like it to sit at the bottom :(, but it seems to be defying anything I try, it does not auto rotate, like other views, and my guess is, its related to it being positioned when the phone is just starting up o.0

Comment: @Ben_hawk Then phonegap should be mentioned somewhere in your question!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGPoint bottomCenter;
if (deviceOrientation == 1) {

bottomCenter = CGPointMake((screenBounds.size.width / 2), (screenBounds.size.height * 0.8));
} 
else if (deviceOrientation == 4) {
bottomCenter = CGPointMake((screenBounds.size.width / 2), (screenBounds.size.height * 0.8));
}
```

In landscape mode you are taking wrong width and height

In landscape mode width and height also change.